# jQuery extend, cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

I have this code:

```
var viewport = $(window),
    viewport_height = viewport.height();

var _topPanel = jQuery.extend({
    el: $('.js-lp_top'),
    //
    height: function() {
        var self = this;

        self.el.css('min-height', viewport_height);
    },
    scroll : function() {
        var self = this;
        var scrolled = viewport.scrollTop();

        viewport.on('scroll', function() {
            self.el.css({
                'top': (49 - (scrolled / viewport_height) * 80) + '%'
            });
        });
    }
});
var topPanel = new _topPanel.height().scroll();
```

And an jQuery error that `Cannot read property 'css' of undefined`. What i'm doing wrong? Thx for help.

Comment: Post the pertinent HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first examine this line of code.

```
 var topPanel = new _topPanel.height().scroll();
```

The keyword `new` creates a new empty object. Inside the `height` function, the `this` keyword refers to this new object, which of course doesn't have an `el` property. `self.el` is undefined, hence the error message `Cannot read property 'css' of undefined`

There are two changes to make here:

1. Ensure your `height` and `scroll` functions returns `this`, to support function chaining
2. Don't include the `new` keyword when invoking the `height` function

Here's the modified code:

```
var _topPanel = jQuery.extend({
    el: $('.js-lp_top'),
    //
    height: function () {
        var self = this;

        self.el.css('min-height', viewport_height);
        return self;
    },
    scroll: function () {
        var self = this;
        var scrolled = viewport.scrollTop();

        viewport.on('scroll', function () {
            self.el.css({
                'top': (49 - (scrolled / viewport_height) * 80) + '%'
            });
        });
        return self;
    }
});
var topPanel = _topPanel.height().scroll();
```